Solving a 2-variable recurrence relation along the boundary
The following recurrence shows up when computing the expectations of the quantum harmonic oscillator:
$$a(n,j)=a(n-1,j+1)+2j(2j-1)\,a(n-1,j-1)+(4j+1)\,a(n-1,j)\,,$$
with the conditions $a(n,n)=(2n)!\,$ and  $a(n,-1)=a(n,n+1)=0\,$.
I am not interested in solving for the general $a(n,j)$, although I did try (and failed) using the methods of 2-variable generating functions. Instead, I am interested in solving for
$$b(n)=a(n,0)\,,$$
a problem which I know is quite related to Dyke paths, and I know has solution:
$$b(n)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\,.$$

Without using induction, how can I obtain $b(n)$?


Could you write the recurrence in $b(n)$ that interests you?

@Cesareo I am not sure I understand your question. I am interested in finding $b(n)=a(n,0)$ for all $n$. Crucially, I don't have a recurrence for $b(n)$; I only have one for $a(n,j)$, with the two dimensions inherently coupled.
